# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch while memory allocation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing

To optimize my code i did memory allocation but now I am getting this error, Please have a look at it

```
I(:,:,:,:)=zeros(Height,Width,3,nframes,'uint8');



for i=1:nframes

I(:,:,:,i) = read(xyloObj,i);

end

S=zeros(Height,Width,3,nframes,'uint8');

for i=2:nframes

    S(:,:,:,i)=I(:,:,:,i)-I(:,:,:,i-1);

    Q(:,:,:,i)=var(double(S(:,:,:,i)));

end
```

Comment: Which line are you getting this ERROR? What are the variables that you have in that line?

Comment: S(:,:,:,i)=I(:,:,:,i)-I(:,:,:,i-1); This is the line where i am getting the error.

Comment: put in `I(:,:,:,i)` and `I(:,:,:,i-1)` see if you get same sized matrices, if so, check the size of I against S and see if they have the same dimensions

Comment: If your matrices for each `i` are not of the same size, consider using a [cell array](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) to store them.

Comment: I have edited the question. The actual source of my error is this line Q(:,:,:,i)=var(double(S(:,:,:,i))) . The size  of [var(double(S(:,:,:,i)))] is 1* 320 *3 , and the size of [Q(:,:,:,i)] is 240*320*3.